# Implementing Dart Interfaces and Abstract Classes

Tags: dart

I am a Dart beginner and I've been following the official Dart documentation. However, I've encountered some difficulties understanding the section on interfaces and abstract classes (https://dart.dev/language#interfaces-and-abstract-classes). The documentation provides the following `Spacecraft` class.

```
class Spacecraft {
  String name;

  DateTime? launchDate;
  int? get launchYear => launchDate?.year;

  Spacecraft(this.name, this.launchDate);
  Spacecraft.unlaunched(String name) : this(name, null);

  void describe() {
    print('Spacecraft: $name');
    var launchDate = this.launchDate;

    if (launchDate != null) {
      
      int years = DateTime.now().difference(launchDate).inDays ~/ 365;
      print('Launched: $launchYear ($years years ago)');
    } else {
      print('Unlaunched');
    }
  }
}
void main() {
  var voyager = Spacecraft('Voyager I', DateTime(1977, 9, 5));
  voyager.describe();
}
```

Unfortunately, the documentation does not provide the implementation for `MockSpaceship` and `Describable`.

```
class MockSpaceship implements Spacecraft {
  // ···
}
```

and

```
abstract class Describable {
  void describe();

  void describeWithEmphasis() {
    print('=========');
    describe();
    print('=========');
  }
}
```

I am a bit lost on how to proceed with the implementation of MockSpaceship and also on how to integrate the Describable class into my existing code.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to complete these implementations and merge everything together in a manner consistent with Dart's best practices.

Thank you in advance!